# Why $L$ = { $uc^nu$ | $u$ ∈ $P$, $n > 0$ } isn't context-free?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

$P$ is the set of all words of even length on {0,1}.

Hi, i tried using pumping lemma to see why $L$ isn't a context-free language, but there's a decomposition where none of all three properties is violated ($|v|$ and $|x|$ iterating factors on $c^n$.).

I know this doesn't mean it's context-free, but to be sure it is not, what can i do?.
If it isn't context-free i can't find an equivalent PDA, but why? has it to do with the stack?

As always, really thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem using the pumping lemma here.

Assume that $L$ is context-free. Let $n$ be its pumping length and $u = 1^n0^nc1^n0^n\in L$.

By the pumping lemma, there exists a decomposition $u = vwxyz$ such that:

1. $|wxy|\leqslant n$;
2. $|wy| > 0$;
3. for all $k\geqslant 0$, $vw^kxy^kz\in L$.

Let us distinguish cases:

- if $w$ or $y$ contains $c$, then $vxz$ does not contain any $c$ and therefore is not in $L$;
- if $w$ and $y$ are on the same side regarding the $c$, then $vxz = u_1cu_2$ with $|u_1|\neq |u_2|$, therefore is not in $L$;
- if $w$ and $y$ are of different length, the same reasonning as above can be done;
- since $|wxy| \leqslant n$, that means that $wxy$ is contained in the $0^nc1^n$ part, and that $w = 0^p$ and $y = 1^p$ with $1\leqslant p < \frac{n}2$. That means that $vxz = 1^n0^{n-p}c1^{n-p}0^n$ is not in $L$.

We conclude by contradiction.

Comment: But don't we have to generalize 'c' too? I mean $(1)^n(0)^n (c)^n(1)^n(0)^n$

Comment: The word $u$ is constructed to be a counter-example. There are no restriction over it other than being in the language and of length $\geqslant n$.

Comment: Yes, and it must be chosen correctly to reach a contradiction.